# Running line set for minisplit through soffit

Tags: air-conditioning, heat-pump, copper-tubing, mini-split

I am installing MrCool DIY minisplits. I am wishing that I had just hired a professional, but unfortunately I'm too deep into this to change course at this point.

My question is whether it is okay for line sets to penetrate the exterior wall, go **up** to soffit, go level over to condenser, then down the exterior wall to connect with the condenser. The idea is that there are a number of obstacles along the exterior that could be avoided by going through the soffit, and it would look much nicer in the end (even though notching out and adding a nailer plate for each rafter will be a pain). I have seen discussions about making sure that oil does not get trapped in the wrong parts of the system, and I don't know enough to judge if my idea would cause problems with the performance/longevity of the system.

The installation manual suggests leaving the extra line coiled by the condenser, but I think that would be tacky. If going up to the soffit is kosher, then could I also leave extra line coiled/serpentined horizontally in the soffit? I lean toward coiling, since it feels like there is less chance of kinking the line. If coiling in the soffit leads to some minimal slope in the line, which direction would I want that slope to face (toward condenser or toward the head unit)? Should I coil in the soffit next to the head unit or next to the condenser?

Speaking of slope I have one section of soffit (only affecting one of the head units) that slopes down from head unit at 30-ish degrees for about 8 feet, then level the rest of the way to get to the condenser. Is running the lineset on a slope like that going to be a problem?

So to sum up....

1. Can I run line set **up** to soffit, across, and down to condenser?
2. For one unit in particular, can I run line set up to the soffit, across, sloping down, across, and down to condenser?
3. Can I coil/serpentine extra line in the soffit? If so, what is the best strategy?

In all cases, the condensate drain would still go straight down for at least a few inches after coming out of the exterior wall.

Is this a reasonable plan?

Comment: where is your heat exchanger

Comment: Where is your condensate going to drain?  The problem with going up and back is it can trap the oil but this can be remedied by adding some additional PAG/POE oil not the best way to go a better rout would to get a different inside unit that mounts in the ceiling. The oil is permeable at pressure but it may shorten the system life but I have done similar on older systems adding enough oil so I had enough after several cycles and that system made it for many years but the compressors were much more bullet proof back then.  So it can be done but then the problem is the condensate.

Comment: @Ruskes There is a heat exchanger in the condenser unit outside and in the head unit inside.

Comment: @EdBeal The condensate will still drain straight down after exiting the wall, but the line set will go up (all covered by a line set cover).

Comment: Vibration and thermal expansion are the reason for coiling.

Comment: @ruskes, mr cool comes with a fixed line set that is why they recommend coiling not for vibration. And it would be fine in the soffit.